# JavaScript e Php, Mensagem de Exclusão

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Boa tarde!

Por favor, podem me dizer aonde estou errando nesse código? o procedimento de exclusão não funciona quando eu passo o parâmetro no onclick 
Obrigado!

Button

```
<!-- repassando o id codificado através do get -->
<form method='GET' action=''>
<td><button onclick="exclusao(<?=$id?>)" name="excluir" id="excluir" type="submit" value="<?=$id?>" class="btn btn btn-primary center-block">Excluir</button>
</form></td>
```

// javascript

```
/* Mensagem de Alerta ao excluir um registro um registro */
function exclusao(id) {
    var msg = confirm("Atenção: Deseja Excluir esse Registro?")
    if (msg){
        console.log(id);
        alert("Arquivo excluido com sucesso!");
        window.location.href=("rsociais_exclusao.php?i="+id);

    }
    else{
        alert("Operação Cancelada, o Registro não será Excluído!");


    }
}
```

exclusao_rsociais.php

```
<?php   
// ******************************** ATENÇÃO OS DADOS SERÃO EXCLUIDOS **************************//

        // repassando o id para a variavel
        $id = $_GET['excluir'];

        // Decodificando o id que estava criptografado, para o usuário não ver o id
        $id_rsociais = decodehash_id($id);


        // chamando a classe seo
        $rsociais = new Rsociais();

        // chamando a classe responsavel pelo crud  seo_Crud
        $rsociais_crud = new Rsociais_crud();

        $rsociais->setId_rsociais($id_rsociais[0]);
        $rsociais_crud->RsociaisDelete($rsociais);
    ?>
```

Comment: Aonde acontece o erro? Qual erro você está recebendo?

Comment: não apresenta erro nenhum!, o alerta tb não está sendo exibido, sem contar q o console tb não retorna o valor do id, mas o navegador atualiza a pagina e exibe o id codificado na URL, mas não exclui o registro

Comment: a variável GET está setada para receber o parâmetro excluir, você está enviando o parâmetro i, o correto seria window.location.href=("rsociais_exclusao.php?excluir="+id); Outro problema é que o botão está dentro de um form, não tem necessidade.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda e dica! funcionou!!!  outro detalhe é que estava faltando aspas ao repassar o parâmetro no onclick exclusao()  abraços,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametro do get é i  `window.location.href=("rsociais_exclusao.php?i="+id);` portanto   deveria ser   `$id = $_GET['i'];`

```
 // repassando o id para a variável

$id = $_GET['i'];

    // Decodificando o id que estava criptografado, para o usuário não ver o id
    $id_rsociais = decodehash_id($id);


    // chamando a classe seo
    $rsociais = new Rsociais();

    // chamando a classe responsavel pelo crud  seo_Crud
    $rsociais_crud = new Rsociais_crud();

    $rsociais->setId_rsociais($id_rsociais[0]);
    $rsociais_crud->RsociaisDelete($rsociais);
```

Answer (score 2):

Problema Resolvido! Felipe Duarte e Leo Caracciolo me ajudaram!!!

abaixo estou postando o código com as alterações .... para quem precisar! abraços, Diego

Button

```
<!-- repassando o id codificado através do get -->
<td><button onclick="exclusao('<?=$id?>')" name="excluir" id="excluir" value="<?=$id?>" class="btn btn btn-primary center-block">Excluir</button></td>
```

// javascript

```
/* Mensagem de Alerta ao excluir um registro */
function exclusao($id) {
    var msg = confirm("Atenção: Deseja Excluir esse Registro?");

    if (msg){
        alert("Arquivo excluído com sucesso!");
        window.location.href=("exclusao_rsociais.php?excluir="+$id);

    }
    else{
        alert("Operação Cancelada, o Registro não será Excluído!");


    }
}
```

exclusao_rsociais.php

```
// ******************************** ATENÇÃO OS DADOS SERÃO EXCLUIDOS **************************//

// repassando o id para a variavel
$id = $_GET['excluir'];

// Decodificando o id que estava criptografado, para o usuário não ver o id
$id_rsociais = decodehash_id($id);


// chamando a classe seo
$rsociais = new Rsociais();

// chamando a classe responsavel pelo crud  
$rsociais_crud = new Rsociais_crud();

$rsociais->setId_rsociais($id_rsociais[0]);
$rsociais_crud->RsociaisDelete($rsociais);

// retornando para a pagina de consulta
echo " <script> document.location.href='rsociais.php'; </script>"
```